# Cannot delete file because it is being used by another process, ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.Net Core with MVC for creating an app. I am using visual studio and IIS express currently.
Below is my current project structure:

*project directory

-wwwroot

-areas

-attachments

-controllers

-models

-views

I currently store images inside the attachments folder.

Previously I have written something like that inside my startup.cs

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Attachments")),
            RequestPath = "/Attachments"
        });
```

I have also done something like this below:

```
appendImage(@Url.Content("~/Attachments/")+result.fileName);
```

I did this to display an image on my view. The image is displayed successfully.

What I am trying to achieve now is the on the UI allow the user to make a choice to delete the files inside that attachments folder

I tried the following code:

```
string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
string fullImagePath = Path.Combine(contentRootPath +   "\\Attachments", currentItemToDelete.FileName);

if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullImagePath))
{
  try{
       System.IO.File.Delete(fullImagePath);
  }catch(Exception e){
       operationResult = "Attachment Path. Internal Server Error";
  }
}
```

The execution does enter the `if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullImagePath))`
but it raises an exception when it reaches `System.IO.File.Delete`. The exception states that the file which resides in that path is being used by another process. And thus I cannot delete the file. The only process that is accessing the file is the web app I am creating/debugging at the same time. How do I prevent this exception from happening? Do I have to use other kind of code to delete the file ?

EDIT to include more details:

Inside my view(index.cshtml):

appendImage is a javascript function:

```
function appendImage(imgSrc) {
        var imgElement = document.createElement("img");
        imgElement.setAttribute('src', imgSrc);


        if (imgSrc.includes(null)) {
            imgElement.setAttribute('alt', '');
        }
        imgElement.setAttribute('id', "img-id");

        var imgdiv = document.getElementById("div-for-image");
        imgdiv.appendChild(imgElement);
}
```

That function is called below:

```
$.ajax({
                url:'@Url.Action("GetDataForOneItem", "Item")',
                type: "GET",
                data: { id: rowData.id },
                success: function (result) {
                    removeImage();
                    appendImage(@Url.Content("~/Attachments/")+result.fileName);
                    $("#edit-btn").attr("href", '/Item/EditItem?id=' + result.id);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                }
        });
```

After calling appendImage(); I change the href of a `<a>` tag. When the user clicks on the link, the user is directed to another page(edit.cshtml). In the page, the image which resides in that path is also being displayed with code like this:

`<img src="@Url.Content("~/Attachments/"+Model.FileName)" alt="item image" />`

In this new page(edit.cshtml), there is a delete button. Upon clicking the delete button, the execution of the program goes to the controller which is this controller function:

```
[HttpPost]
public string DeleteOneItem(int id)
{
        //query the database to check if there is image for this item.
        var currentItemToDelete = GetItemFromDBDateFormatted(id);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentItemToDelete.FileName))
        {
            //delete the image from disk. 
            string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
            string fullImagePath = Path.Combine(contentRootPath + "\\Attachments", currentItemToDelete.FileName);

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullImagePath))
            {
                try
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(fullImagePath);
                }catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
            }

        }

        return "";

 }
```

EDIT to answer question:

Add in

```
System.GC.Collect(); 
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

before system.io.file.delete

Comment: Is the image you want to delete also being displayed (used) in the code? If so, I would guess you would need to “release” this file from any object using it before you will be able to delete it. The line `appendImage(@Url.Content("~/Attachments/")+result.fileName);` … appears to be “using” the file.

Comment: @JohnG, that piece of code appendImage(); is called inside my view(.cshtml). The piece of code the delete the file (system.io.file.delete) resides in the controller. How do I release the file? I have to write some other code inside the controller before system.io.file.delete is being called?

Comment: It depends on what appendImage() is doing. Can you share the relevant code inside appendImage()? There is probably some file I/O logic in there that is not releasing/closing/disposing a stream when it needs to.

Comment: @AashishKoirala, I edited the question to include more details.

Comment: Have you looked at any of [the other questions about this error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+being+used+by+another+process)?

Comment: @HereticMonkey. I have seemingly resolved the problem by adding these 2 lines before system.io.file.delete :  System.GC.Collect(); 
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
try
{
 System.GC.Collect(); 
 System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); 
 System.IO.File.Delete(fullImagePath);
}
catch(Exception e){
}
```

Answer (score 7):

you can replace your C# method DeleteOneItem with this given code. may be it might work.

```
[HttpPost]
public string DeleteOneItem(int id)
{
    //query the database to check if there is image for this item.
    var currentItemToDelete = GetItemFromDBDateFormatted(id);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentItemToDelete.FileName))
    {
        //delete the image from disk. 
        string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
        string fullImagePath = Path.Combine(contentRootPath + "\\Attachments", currentItemToDelete.FileName);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullImagePath))
        {
            try
            {
                System.GC.Collect();
                System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                System.IO.File.Delete(fullImagePath);

            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```